# Reading two matrices

Tags: java, matrix

I have a text file with two matrices in the format shown in the figure, the figure is just an example the matrices size may vary.

please help me read the two matrices.

(the first and the second matrices are separated by a blank line)

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
0 1 5 6

5 6 9
6 4 3
9 7 5
9 8 0
```

Comment: Show what you did yet? Community will help you to debug blockers.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: First things first: do you know how to read from text files?   If not, have a look at [this sectino of the Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html).

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for text or code blocks. Instead, paste the text or code block, select it using the mouse, and press the `{}` button in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

To parse a file to 2d matrices, you have to read file line by line, split a line to get member of matrix row, each time you meet blank line, add new matrix to matrices list.

Following code represent how to do it. `int[][][] matrices` stores all read matrices from file (of cause, this code does not validate file content, and is not optimized code, just show how to do)

```
int[][][] matrices = new int[][][] {}; //array of matrix
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new FileReader(new File("test.txt")))) 
{
    String line;
    int index = 0; //current matrix
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if (!line.trim().equals(""))
        {
            // parse line to int array
            String[] memb = line.split(" ");
            int[] arr = new int[memb.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < memb.length; i++)
                arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(memb[i]);

            // add new matrix
            if (index == matrices.length)
                matrices = Arrays.copyOf(matrices, matrices.length + 1);

            int[][] matrix = matrices[index];
            if (matrix == null)
                matrix = new int[][] {};

            // add int array to matrix (line)
            matrix = Arrays.copyOf(matrix, matrix.length + 1);
            matrix[matrix.length - 1] = arr;
            matrices[index] = matrix;
        }
        else
        {
            // flag to increase matrices size
            index++;
        }
    }
}

// test output
for (int i = 0; i < matrices.length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < matrices[i].length; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < matrices[i][j].length; k++)
        {
            System.out.print(matrices[i][j][k]);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("\r\n");
    }
    System.out.print("\r\n");
}
```